# Create Mail, fill with content and open it in Mail Client

Tags: email, xpages

I want to create a new document in javascript and generate a new mail with it. I fill the body, sendto and subject of the mail and then I want to open the mail in Lotus Notes Client.

How can I open this mail in the mail client?

Comment: Hi M. Schaetzl, how do you create the mail? Did you use the SSJS code from Mark Leusink?

Comment: Not yet. I tried the mail creation before I found the solution of Mark Leusink. So in the future I will use that one as far as possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This button creates a new mail with content in the To field, Subject field and Body field coming from fields on the XPage (using client-side Javascript). The logic works with whatever defailt mail client you have (IBM Notes, MS Outlook and other mail clients).

```
<xp:button id="sendMail" label="Send mail">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="false">
        <xp:this.script><![CDATA[
        window.location.href="mailto:" + encodeURIComponent(dojo.byId("#{id:mailTo}").innerHTML) + "?subject=" + encodeURIComponent(dojo.byId("#{id:mailSubject}").innerHTML) + "&body=" + encodeURIComponent(dojo.byId("#{id:mailBody}").innerHTML);
        ]]></xp:this.script>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
```

Comment: When I use your code I just get a mail with empty SendTo, Subject and Body (I named my fields just as yours). Is there a problem with the "innerHTML" command? Because when I use encodeURIComponent(dojo.byId("#{id:mailTo}").value I at least get the value, but not with the innerHTML command.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it this way:
- Click on a button to create the SendTo, Subject and HTML-Body of the Mail
- Then a new XPage opens containing the contents of the Mail - I can edit them now or just click on a button "Send Mail"
- Using the SSJS code from Mark Leusink I then send the HTML Mail

```
var mail = new HTMLMail();
mail.setTo( docMail.getItemValue("SendTo") );
mail.setSubject( docMail.getItemValue("Subject") );
mail.addHTML( docMail.getItemValue("dBody") );
mail.send();
```

The advantage in this case is, that I can save the mail in the database and not in the mail file of the current user.